# Name of this state representation idea without local variables

Tags: scheme, racket, counter, state, conceptual

I know this is maybe an oddball idea, but I thought might as well give it a try to ask here.

I was experimenting in Racket about state representation without local variables.
The idea was defining a function that prints it's parameter value and if called again gives me another value. Since pure functions called with the same parameter always produce the same result, my workaround-idea got me the following.

```
(define (counter n)
  (displayln n)
  (λ () (counter (add1 n)))) ; unapplied lambda so it doesn't go in a loop
```

Then I devised a function to call `counter` and its resulting lambdas a certain number of times.

```
(define (call proc n)
  (unless (zero? n)
    (let ([x (proc)])
      (call x (sub1 n)))))
```

Which results in this:

```
> (call (counter 0) 5)
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

What is the name for the concept applied here? Propably it's something trivial what you need in real applications all the time, but since I have no experience in that respect yet so I can't pinpoint a name for it. Or maybe I just complicated something very simple, but nonetheless I would appreciate an answer so I can look further into it.

Sorry if my question is not clear enough, but english is not my first language and to ask about things I have no name for makes me feel kinda uncertain.

Comment: The title implies that this represents state "without local variables", but it's not correct, the `x` in your code acts as a local variable...

Comment: Well yeah, but I still can manually call e.g. `((((((counter 0))))))` which would return the same numbers (and a lambda), without assigning `x`. I just defined `call` to not have type it like this. Would this still count as local variable?

Comment: Yes, because you depend on the fact that the updated solution is stored somewhere _outside_ the original procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) to save state: a `lambda` form stores the environment in which it was defined, and you keep redefining the procedure (called `x` in your code), so each time it "remembers" a new value for `n`.

Another way to do the same would be to let the procedure itself keep track of the value - in other words, `counter` should remember the current `n` value between invocations. This is what I mean:

```
(define (counter initial)
  (let ((n (sub1 initial)))
    (lambda ()
      (set! n (add1 n))
      n)))
```

In the above code, the first invocation of `counter` returns a new `lambda` that closes over `n`, and each invocation of that `lambda` modifies `n` and returns its new value. Equivalently, we could use Racket-specific syntax for currying and the `begin0` special form to achieve the same effect:

```
(define ((counter n))
  (begin0
    n
    (set! n (add1 n))))
```

Either way, notice how the procedure "remembers" its previous value:

```
(define proc (counter 0))
(proc)
=> 0
(proc)
=> 1
```

And we would `call` it like this:

```
(define (call proc n)
  (unless (zero? n)
    (displayln (proc))
    (call proc (sub1 n))))

(call (counter 0) 5)
=> 0
   1
   2
   3
   4
```

Also notice that the above fixes an off-by-one error originally in your code - the procedure was being called *six times* (from `0` to `5`) and not five times as intended, that happened because `call` invokes `counter` five times, but you called `counter` one more time outside, when evaluating `(counter 0)`.

Comment: I knew about the (in this case not really) off-by-one. I just didn't bother changing anything because it was irrelevant to my problem. But thanks overall.